# Mysql create table statement error

Tags: mysql

I have a problem while creating a table by using below MySQL query. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with a query?

This is the query.

```
CREATE TABLE asset (
    id INT NOT NULL auto_increment
    ,amc VARCHAR(255)
    ,df VARCHAR(255)
    ,asset_code VARCHAR(255)
    ,camera VARCHAR(255)
    ,condition VARCHAR(255)
    ,description VARCHAR(255)
    ,disposal_date VARCHAR(255)
    ,frequency VARCHAR(255)
    ,GROUP VARCHAR(255)
    ,kind VARCHAR(255)
    ,leased_to VARCHAR(255)
    ,locationx VARCHAR(255)
    ,locationy VARCHAR(255)
    ,maintenance VARCHAR(255)
    ,manufacturer VARCHAR(255)
    ,model VARCHAR(255)
    ,name VARCHAR(255)
    ,purchase_date VARCHAR(255)
    ,purchase_price VARCHAR(255)
    ,service_provider VARCHAR(255)
    ,STATUS VARCHAR(255)
    ,sub_model VARCHAR(255)
    ,tag_type VARCHAR(255)
    ,warranty VARCHAR(255)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't use keywords _ever_ would be the right answer. youre inviting doom and confusion onto any future sql statement creator for this table if you do. rename `GROUP` and `CONDITION` to avoid this confusion to your future self!

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP` and `CONDITION` are reserved keywords. Either escape them using backticks or better use a different name such as `GROUP_NAME`, `CONDITION_NAME` etc.